# Change language for Google reCaptcha v3

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, recaptcha

I using Google reCaptcha v3 for contactform 7 to my Wordpress site. There is always a little fane in the lower right corner that shows the privacy term. But it is in Danish even the whole website is in English. How can I change the language of it? [image]